# Putting Google Sheets Under GitHub Version Control

Tags: github, google-drive-api

I have a Google Drive with a nested hierarchy of folders including Google Sheets.
To support a downstream development process i need to get the folders and the files into GitHub.
Whats the recommended way of doing it?

1. I dont see an addon for GDrive.
2. I would rather not pay for a Zapier
   or Automate.IO solution if i can avoid it.
3. Using Google File Stream doesnt work it throws an IO error after adding to git when committing.
4. Downloading the files into an archive and then expanding
   it to add into a local git repo almost works but then breaks because
   the path length of the hierarchy is too long.
5. Python script ?

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: For me, it's better to use Python script for this. You could check this code from [github](https://github.com/larsks/gitdriver) for more details. You will need to create an OAuth client id and secret for use with this application, the Drive API [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) has links to the necessary steps.